# huggingface model: git clone Stuck at "Filtering content: 40% (2/5)" when cloning repository

Tags: huggingface, llama

huggingface model: git clone Stuck at "Filtering content: 40% (2/5)" when cloning repository
When try to git clone https://huggingface.co/chavinlo/alpaca-native repository, the download gets stuck at status "Filtering content: 40% (2/5)" and no progress for long long time.

I tried :

1. git lfs install
2. git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000